# Animation on a Transparent Panel

Tags: java, animation, panel, transparency

I want to animate an object on a transparent panel (in this case `upperPanel`), but once the animated object has been added to the `upperPanel`, its background is no longer transparent.

The `upperPanel` is in the `bottomPanel`. The background of `bottomPanel` is red, so you can see if  `upperPanel` is transparent.

Code of the Frame:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NewFrame extends JFrame{
    
      public static void main(String args[]){
          JFrame f = new JFrame();
          AnimatedObject a = new AnimatedObject();
          JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
          JPanel upperPanel = new JPanel();
          bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
          bottomPanel.setSize(300, 300);
          bottomPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
          upperPanel.setSize(300, 300);
          upperPanel.setOpaque(false);
          upperPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
          f.add(bottomPanel);
          bottomPanel.add(upperPanel);
          upperPanel.add(a);
          f.setSize(400,400);
          f.setVisible(true);
          f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      }
}
```

Code of the animated Object:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class AnimatedObject extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private boolean direction = true;
    Timer tm = new Timer(50, this);

    public AnimatedObject() {
        initComponents();
        tm.start();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        g.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);
        System.out.println("Test gesetzt("+x+"|"+y+")");
    }
    
    public void moveForward() {
        x = x + 30;
        repaint();
        System.out.println("(" + x + "|" + y + ")");
    }

    public void moveBackwards() {
        x = x - 30;
        repaint();
        System.out.println("(" + x + "|" + y + ")");
    }

    public void moveDown() {
        y = y + 30;
        repaint();
        System.out.println("(" + x + "|" + y + ")");
    }

    public void moveUp() {
        y = y - 30;
        repaint();
        System.out.println("(" + x + "|" + y + ")");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if (direction){
           moveDown();
       }
       else {
           moveUp();
       }
       if (((y >= 270) && (direction)) || ((y <= 0) && (!direction))) {
        moveForward();
        direction = !direction;
       }
      }
}
```

Comment: Because you panels are using `BorderLayout`s, this will force the child component to fill the entire available space of the parent, because `AnimatedObject` is not transparent itself, it's filling the space of it's parent with an opaque fill color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your panels are using `BorderLayout`s, this will force the child component to fill the entire available space of the parent, because `AnimatedObject` is not transparent itself, it's filling the space of it's parent with an opaque fill color.

You can test this by changing the background color of `AnimatedObject`

```
public AnimatedObject() {
    setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    tm.start();
}
```

[image: Blue background]

A simple fix would be to make `AnimatedObject` transparent as well.

```
public AnimatedObject() {
    setOpaque(false);
    tm.start();
}
```

[image: Transparent]